# How do I handle a NA value in effect function?

Tags: r, na, effect

I have a data set with one outlier to which I assigned a "NA". Due to this, or so it seems, effect() does not work.

```
> eff.bs3 <- effect("SHADE", model.bspyield3)
> eff.bs3$fit[2]/eff.bs3$fit[1]*100
[1] NA
```

How could I solve this problem? Something like na.rm=TRUE didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `na.rm = TRUE`?

Comment: Did you mean `effects` or is this a function from some package?

Comment: You can subset your data to exclude the outlier and then run the script. Or try something like na.action=na.exclude.

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude the data in the first place:

This is with the `drop_na()` function from `dplyr`

```r
library(tidyverse)
eff.bs3 <- effect("SHADE", drop_na(model.bspyield3))
```

- Note that I'm putting the dataframe `model.bspyield3` inside the drop_na function

You could also make a new df for further analysis by using:

`clean.model.bspyield3 = drop_na(model.bspyield3)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. As it turned out, the "NA" result is not due to the NA-value of one row, because I removed the row and still get "NA". It seems there is some problem with the factor "press" because when I use this

lm(yield ~ press+site*SHADE*fertilization*irrigation)

it works out, however, I want to take

lm(yield ~ press+samppos+site*SHADE*fertilization*irrigation)

and then I get "NA"s again. "Press" is a factor with two levels (yes/no)... What could be the problem?